# How to use angular material virtual repeater in angular components?

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I am trying to put angular material virtual repeat inside an angular component.
However I receive an empty content when I load this. Not sure, what is wrong in the code?
I have created a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/kPsMKFKhJepZNakhvrSt?p=preview) to test this.

I have used

```
self.dynamicItems = new DynamicItems();
```

instead of 
`this.dynamicItems = new DynamicItems();` from the angular material [sample](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/virtualRepeat).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per angular material documentation, the virtual-repeat needs pre-defined height. [md-virtual-repeat does not work without predefined height](https://github.com/angular/material/issues/4314)

Answer (score 0):

Check the console on your Plunkr.  You don't have `taskFactory` defined anywhere in your code.

```
angular.js:13920 Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: taskFactoryProvider <- taskFactory
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/$injector/unpr?p0=taskFactoryProvider%20%3C-%20taskFactory
  at angular.js:68
  at angular.js:4511
  at Object.getService [as get] (angular.js:4664)
  at angular.js:4516
  at getService (angular.js:4664)
  at injectionArgs (angular.js:4688)
  at Object.invoke (angular.js:4710)
  at $controllerInit (angular.js:10354)
  at nodeLinkFn (angular.js:9263)
  at angular.js:9673
```

Comment: i am sorry, can you try now?